# Cabal install package fails weirdly

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install

I access internet through a proxy and have appropriately set up the environment variables. The problem is that whenever I am trying to install any package through cabal, it fails with a

`connect: does not exist (Connection Refused)` error.

But if I run `cabal update -v3`, it successfully makes the connection and retrieves the update information.

```
$ cabal --version   
cabal-install version 1.20.0.2
using version 1.20.0.1 of the Cabal library
```

Edit: I'm running **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @VivekRai Does this happen to you sometimes or everytime ? I have experienced this problem occasionally under a proxy.

Comment: @Sibi As far as I know, it has been happening since two days. I would change the proxy and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. The problem is solved by using `-E` with `sudo` command.

`sudo -E cabal install <package>`

Although, I don't understand why `cabal update` could work but not `cabal install`.